# Value in EditText is set on second click only

Tags: android, datepicker, dynamic-forms

I have an adapter where there is dynamic form generated using switch case. all the case are working but in case of CASE:"NepaliDate", the date is set only in second click. The following is my case:

```
case "NEPALI_DATE":

            holder.et = new EditText(context);
            list.add(holder.et);
            holder.et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
            holder.sifarismainLayout.addView(holder.et);
            holder.et.setFocusable(false);
            holder.et.setCursorVisible(false);

            holder.et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int current_month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
                        Log.e("currMonth", String.valueOf(current_month));

                        if(current_month == 4 || current_month == 5 || current_month == 6 || current_month == 7 ||
                            current_month == 8 || current_month == 9 || current_month == 10 ||
                            current_month == 11 || current_month == 12) {

                            com.hornet.dateconverter.DatePicker.DatePickerDialog dpd = com.hornet.dateconverter.DatePicker.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(chooseSifarisAdapter.this, now.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 57, now.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 3,
                                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                            dpd.show(manager, "Datepickerdialog");
                        }

                        else {
                            com.hornet.dateconverter.DatePicker.DatePickerDialog dpd = com.hornet.dateconverter.DatePicker.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                                    chooseSifarisAdapter.this,
                                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 57,
                                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 9,
                                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            );
                            dpd.show(manager, "Datepickerdialog");

                      }
                        holder.et.setText(nepaliDate);

            });
            break;
```

To use com.hornet.dateconverter.DatePicker.DatePickerDialog i have to implement a method which contains an override method as follows:

```
 @Override
public void onDateSet(com.hornet.dateconverter.DatePicker.DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        i1 = i1 + 1;
        String startdate;
        startdate = (i + "/" + i1 + "/" + i2);
        DateConverter dc = new DateConverter();
        Model outputOfConversion = dc.getEnglishDate(i, i1, i2);
        int year = outputOfConversion.getYear();
        int month = outputOfConversion.getMonth();
        int day = outputOfConversion.getDay();
        month = month + 1;
        startDate = (year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
        nepaliDate = i + "-" + i1 + "-" + i2;
```

Using above code the value is set only on second click. Suppose I choose a date, this date wont be visible at EditText at exact time rather the date will be clicked on second time i click the EditText. Since i have used holder, the exact EditText should be used. please help me?

Comment: try to remove focus if it is there in xml

Comment: @ShylendraMadda xml only consists of a linear layout bro.

Comment: no focus is used

Comment: an EditText may gain focus on click

Answer (score 0):

After this line `holder.et = new EditText(context);` you can set the **et** to be not focusable. Because the first click can be to turn the focus to your EditText so to avoid that, since it will not be editable change it's focusable property to false this way:  `holder.et.setFocusable(false)`.

**EDIT:**
According to what I see with your code:
On the first click your `nepaliDate` is empty and when you set the text to your edittext you set an empty string.

After the first click, when the DatePicker pops up and you choose the date, your `nepaliDate` has now a value because it's attributed inside `onDateSet()` callback.

But this time, you are not setting the value of `nepaliDate` to `holder.et`,

So when you click for the second time, I guess, your `nepaliDate` still has the last value.

I think, it should be better to call `holder.et.setText(nepaliDate)` inside `onDateSet()` callback. You can create a reference of `holder.et` on click, that will be accessible inside `onDateSet()`.

That's my point of view

Comment: did you add the line? is it still focusable?

Comment: i added the line. actually a calender is to be poped up when that EditText is clicked. It is still being poped up

Comment: Does it popup at first click? If yes you are in a good way. But my simple test question is, after popup what did you want to achieve according to your code above.

Comment: yes after first click it pops up. After the date picker pops up whenever i chose any date i want it to be set on that EditText. but  the date is set there on second click only.

Comment: Why is `holder.et.setText(nepaliDate);` only called in `else` block and not inside `if` too?

Comment: i am sorry there was a mistake. The holder.et.setText(nepaliDate) is outside the if-else statement. I still have same problem. The date is set after second click only.

Comment: Another thing, I see that `nepaliDate` is set inside `onDateSet()` callback, my question is **when is this called**? after click? onclick? or after date pick?